# Send Push notifications from Python to Chrome in Production . Not planning to use OneSignal. Can you please suggest?

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome, push-notification, push

I want to send Push Notification from a Python file to Chrome .
Also, I want to give an option to open a dashboard via the Push notification.

What can be used here ?
Not planning to use 3rd party apps such as OneSignal , as I have to deploy this in Production .

Really looking for some suggestions.

Also I have created a web extension that creates a push notification with the following info :

( Problem : - This message is static . I want it to be dynamically updated .

```
       - Also, I want it the event to be something else apart from click.
        So that it shows the information once it's updated )
```

manifest.json :

```
{
  "name": "Check Dashboard",
  "version": "1.0",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": [
        "js/app.js"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "background" : {
    "scripts" : ["js/background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "permissions": ["notifications"],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

app.js :

```
console.log('Greet bot!');

const button = document.createElement('button');
button.textContent = 'Check Dashboard!'
document.body.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', button);
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage('', {
    type: 'notification',
    options: {
      title: 'Kafka Alerts',
      message: 'Message',
      iconUrl: '/icon.png',
      type: 'basic'
    }
  });
});
```

background.js :

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(data => {
  if (data.type === 'notification') {
    chrome.notifications.create('', data.options);
  }
});
```